# SQL Server - enclose a long script in single quotations for a function using sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server, function

I have the following example of script. It works fine for this example as it is small and basic. I have a far bigger script with around 50 steps that works fine on its own. As in, hit F5 and does everything, checks if table exists, deletes, writes to tables, drops temps and all results are written to the necessary places. I can't seem to place this large script into this small example:

```
alter procedure james_tester
    @tablename nvarchar(200)
as
BEGIN
    declare @sql nvarchar(max)          

    set @sql =

        ---->
        'select * from'
        ---->

        + @tablename
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
        END

 ---When executing:
 execute james_tester 'dbo.calendar_delete'
```

In my case the section in between the arrows is large and will have numerous variables. I just want to know if there is a function or possibly another way to place a large piece of script at a time in that single quote part. I hope I am describing this sufficiently. What affects the entire script currently from just putting a single quote before and after, is that there are already many comments, and single quotes used in the script that seem to stop the entire script from being highlighted red as text and working fine.

James

Comment: *Don't*? What's the point of using a stored procedure if you end up using dynamic SQL? You get all the SQL Injection "benefits" but no performance improvements. Imagine if somehow `@tablename` was `sys.tables; DROP TABLE Users;--`

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why don't you use an ORM and LINQ on the client?

Comment: I have all the necessary CAATs required for this audit on a script. I would ideally like to have everything in a procedure and just run: execute james_tester 'First_input_table'  'second_input_table' 'period_start' 'period_end' . This just seemed very convenient for me, I just use SQL server and have tables that are updated on my sql server database that I use

Comment: Instead of writing a stored procedure, write a SQLCMD script with variables.    You can even pass the variables from the command line. SQLCMD checks the contents of the variables so there's no way you can pass an entire script in a variable that's supposed to contain a database or table name.

Comment: Ok Panagiotis... Thanks let me do some reading. I know what you meaning with SQL injections risk? OK back to the books for me! Thanks for the direction

Answer (score 1):

It is in fact only the presence of single quotes that will cause problems.  Take the following illustration:

```
declare @bigText varchar(max);

SET @bigText = '"The time has come," the Walrus said, 
"To talk of many things: 
Of shoes and ships and sealing-wax --SQL Comment has no impact 
Of cabbages and kings /* c/c++ comment has no impact */
And why the sea is boiling hot //c# comment has no impact 
And whether pigs have wings."';

 SELECT @bigText;
```

Single quotes can be doubled using regex or some other string replace function, so that should not be too hard either.

BUT (and there always is a but of course) whether the remaining text is a legal SQL string, which you can execute is an entirely different question. The presence of extraneous comments etc. will almost certainly bite you.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks for the response. Parts of my script that are throwing out the quotes include: IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.CLEANSED_T2B_ROAStoresCash_Jan-Mar17', 'U')  and [G L]   in ( '77254','77264','77704','77854',

Comment: How is this script being generated?  It would seem to me that, rather than trying to replace the single quotes with appropriate alternatives, it would be better to fix the script generation??? For example, if those numbers are ints, then the quotes are not needed.

Comment: Hmm... So working around the single quotes issue by including them as variables (including the punctuation) and then seeing whether a different data type could be used for say GL number?.. Just to add. My data is sitting on a test database that only I really have access to...

Comment: Ok... Or store everything in the text that has trouble 's with | instead of ',   then replace the pipe with the ' once you run the text in the procedure. I think that is what you were explaining and seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes to this post and needs to know how this ended. I have no real security risks here of SQL injections etc on the database. The procedure takes a few minutes to run now and just takes this execute in the first two rows to run, with the variables being the periods of SAP backup I need to extract:

```
 execute jc_tester '01' , '02' , '03'
 go



alter procedure jc_tester
@Period1 varchar (3) ,@Period2 varchar (3) , @Period3 varchar (3)
as
begin
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 
replace('...... |    |    |    | ','|','''') + ......... @period1 + 
replace('.....','|','''')
execute sp_executesql @sql
end
```

Each section of text contained ' that I could not seem to avoid and caused havoc when handling as a string. These had to be replace with pipes, then included in a replace statement.

Some other things I learnt along the way that threw my progress out. Don't use Go's in the script to be used in @sql. I did not know this. Rather use ;. Also remove any comments that use the leading '---'. Instead wrap all comments in the script with /*.....*/ . I could swear this made a difference as so many of the comments in the script in @sql were all trailing ---'s.

This process has saved time and now that it is complete I can explore other options other than dynamic sql in a stored procedure and learn how to do it in probably a more appropriate manner. But I'm glad this ran eventually.... Thanks for the guidance.